# Python shows me nothing

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm using Pandas and NumPy for calculations

This is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

imp = pd.read_csv("test.txt", sep=' ', )

imp_vert = imp.iloc[:, 2:].astype(float).replace(0, np.nan).mean()

print(round(imp_vert, 1))
```

This is my test.txt

```
subject1 subject2
7 4
8 8
5 7
4 0
```

and the result is:

```
subject1    6
subject2    6,3
dtype: float64
```

How can I remove dtype: float64 from showing up?

Thank you for your advice.

Comment: Why do you want to remove that , that's generic default with output

Comment: I just want it to show the results, is there a way to only show what the results are from subject1 and subject2 without the extra datatype output

Comment: it gives an error: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'values'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the most "normal" way to access the values is to call the `.tolist()` function:

```
print(round(imp_vert, 1).tolist())
# [4.5, 7.0]
```

After reading your comments, maybe you are more interesting in a dictionary format:

```
print(json.dumps(round(imp_vert, 1).to_dict(), indent=2))
#{
#  "subject1": 4.5,
#  "subject2": 7.0
#}
```

Or csv-format:

```
print(round(imp_vert, 1).to_csv(sep=' '))
#subject1 4.5
#subject2 7.0
```

---

**Setup**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import json

with open("test.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write('''\
subject1 subject2
7 4
8 8
5 7
4 0''')

imp = pd.read_csv("test.txt", sep=' ', )

imp_vert = imp.iloc[2:, :].astype(float).replace(0, np.nan).mean()
```

Comment: @ Anton , thats correct , simplistic approach is `.tolist`

Comment: @Anton , can you pls explain ? `print(json.dumps(round(imp_vert, 1).to_dict(), indent=2))`  , i did not use `json.dump with indent=2` .  Sound intresting ...

Comment: @pygo `json.dumps()` with `s` is pythons way of creating json in string format from a dictionary. By adding `indent=2` we get a nicely-formatted json string (makes it more human-readable).

Comment: @AntonvBR, Thnx for  the explanation :)

Answer (score 1):

In this case you need the `.values` attribute:

```
print(imp_vert.values)
print(round(imp_vert, 1).values)
```

**OR**

```
myarr = imp_vert.values
print(myarr)
```

As i could not reproduce your dataFrame hence, i'll give a way around with this as an example which may help you!

```
>>> df1
      total
cat1  25.23
cat2   3.55
cat3  76.55
cat4  36.48
cat5  45.59
```

When you do below it returns the `dtype` at the end as you are having!

```
>>> np.round(df1['total'], 1)
cat1    25.2
cat2     3.6
cat3    76.6
cat4    36.5
cat5    45.6
Name: total, dtype: float64
```

To remove that at the end we can use lambda exp to ge the result with `applymap`.

```
>>> df1.applymap(lambda x: round(x,1))
      total
cat1   25.2
cat2    3.5
cat3   76.5
cat4   36.5
cat5   45.6
```

Comment: it gives this:TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable

Comment: @Doughnut, can you try again, Just remove the extra parenthesis with `.values`.

Comment: It gives the results in a weird way horizontal with alot of spaces.

Comment: thanks for your help but it gives it like this: [6 6.3] I'd like to have it vertical  and that it says which subject has which number.

Comment: I just update the answer to get it this in a way to give to the way as i could not reproduce the dataset.